# How to call specific method when user click on row in GridView

Tags: asp.net

I add below line to each row and when i click on row in GridView i can select it(means event `GridView_SelectedIndexChanged` hire) how can i change it that when i click on row specific method call

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
in view:

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     function show(id) {
         alert(id);
         // Do something as your need
     }
    </script>

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="DepartmentID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" 
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DepartmentID" HeaderText="DepartmentID" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DepartmentID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Budget" HeaderText="Budget" 
                SortExpression="Budget" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="StartDate" 
                SortExpression="StartDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Administrator" HeaderText="Administrator" 
                SortExpression="Administrator" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

inCodeBehind:
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

             if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='pointer'");

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "show(" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + ");";
        }
```

}

Comment: i want to call method in code behind  because i want to do sth in method but with this code i can't

Comment: check with the following changes:                                   e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select${0}')", e.Row.RowIndex+1));  add an invisible command field <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Link" Visible="false" SelectText="Enroll" />, call your method from the grid view selected index change event.

Comment: Thank you,imagine that i want to set `e.Row.cells[...].Attributes.Add("onclick"...` for two cell and each cell should do specific work (call two different method) with this way i can't do it

Answer (score 1):

Use **[GridView.RowCommand Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx#Y972):** The RowCommand event is raised when a button is clicked in the GridView control. This enables you to provide an event-handling method that performs a custom routine whenever this event occurs.

```
void GridView1_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // If multiple buttons are used in a GridView control, use the
    // CommandName property to determine which button was clicked.
    if(e.CommandName=="YourCommandName")
    {
      // Convert the row index stored in the CommandArgument
      // property to an Integer.
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

      // Retrieve the row that contains the button clicked 
      // by the user from the Rows collection.
      GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

      //Your Code


    }
  }
```

Comment: we can set `CommandName` for buttons, but i want use it for `asp:BoundField`

Comment: '<asp:buttonfield buttontype="Link" commandname="YourCommandName" text="Button"/>'

Comment: but it doesn't have `DataField` and i can't set Text to it from code behind(i create a table and set text to it and set it as DataSource of GridView)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Small" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Link" Visible="false" SelectText="Enroll" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //add css to GridViewrow based on rowState
            e.Row.CssClass = e.Row.RowState.ToString();
            //Add onclick attribute to select row.
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Select${0}')", e.Row.RowIndex));
        }
    }
```

Comment: with this code i can call `selectedIndexChange` method but i want to call my method like `show(DataRow row)`